# Guardar datos con acentos y ñ en mysql desde php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Tengo una función en PHP para guardar datos en BD. Los datos contienen ñ y acentos y esos datos son extraídos de una página de terceros. He intentado muchas formas y no funciona.

Ésta es la función que tengo:

```
public function agregarProduct($name,$brand,$price){

  $sql ="CALL spAddProduct('$name','$brand',$precio);";

    $result= $this->_BD->query($sql);

    $resultado->close();
    $this->_BD->next_result();
}
```

Lo que he intentado es:

- Colocar header en el archivo indicando utf-8.
- He usado `$name = utf8_encode($name);`.
- Tambien he utilizado la funcion `mb_convert_encoding`.
- Otra que utilice fue `iconv(mb_detect_encoding($name, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $name)`.
- He intentado cambiando la collation de la BD a `utf8_general_ci`, `utf8_spanish_ci`, `uft8_default collation`.
- Tambien en mi conexion he usando `$BD->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` y `$BD->set_charset("utf8");`

Nada de lo anterior me funcionó en la base de datos. Ya que por ejemplo si en el argumento `$name` viene `Maíz`, en la base de datos se guarda como `Ma&#237;z`, pero si lo imprimo en pantalla aparece bien (Maíz).

Hice un intento colocando por default un valor a `$name` de la forma `$name = "Maíz";` de esta forma se agrega correctamente a la base de datos.

Una diferencia que encontré es la siguiente:

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($name = 'Maíz');
//esto devuelve UTF-8 y se ingresa correctamente a la BD
echo mb_detect_encoding($name); //$name viene como argumento de la funcion.
//esto devuelve ASCII y se ingresa con los caracteres raros
```

Con esta observación quise ver que devolvía esta misma función al cambiar la variable con las funciones `utf8_encode`, `mb_convert_encoding` y `iconv`, el resultado para todos fue `ASCII`.

¿De qué otra forma podría solucionar esta situación?;

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que lo que te viene de la página de terceros es "Maíz" y no "Ma&#237;z"?

Comment: @israel Para mí también es que lo estás recibiendo así.. probá con `$name = html_entity_decode($name, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");`

Comment: @Mariano Muchisimas gracias, utilice el html_entity_decode y funciono todo a la perfeccion.

Comment: Hola Israel. Este no es un foro clásico de internet donde se pone *[resuelto]* en el título de la pregunta, es más eso es inútil en este sitio. En su lugar, por favor [acepta la respuesta más útil a tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/227).

Comment: Nos [cruzamos ediciones](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12252) @Luiggi `:-)` ... Igual, salvo por ese detalle del título, cabe destacar que es excelente la forma en que hizo la pregunta. -Ojalá todos los que son nuevos haciendo preguntas revisaran todo lo posible antes (como en este caso que revisó todas las codificaciones que encontró). la pregunta está impecable

Comment: @Mariano a veces sucede (:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Problema

Es muy bueno que hayas revisado todas las codificaciones de caracteres (encoding en la base de datos, PHP, todo) antes de hacer la pregunta y que estés usando UTF-8. Así, fue más sencillo ver que estás recibiendo los datos con [entidades HTML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Entidades_HTML) como `&aacute;`, `&#237;`, etc. directamente del HTML, y que **no es un error en la codificación**. Además, seguramente lo estás viendo bien en pantalla porque el propio navegador te lo muestra como corresponde.

---

#### Solución

Para ***decodificar*** (llevar al caracter que corresponde) las [entidades HTML](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Entidades_HTML) usamos la función **[html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php)**.

> **[html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php) (** `string $string` **[,** `int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401` **[,** `string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset")` **]] )**
>
> [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php) es el opuesto de [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) en el sentido de
>   que convierte todas las entidades HTML del string a sus caracteres
>   correspondientes.
>   Para ser más precisos, esta función decodifica todas las entidades (incluyendo todas las entidades numéricas)

---

#### Código

De esta forma, lo podemos usar para todos los datos que recibas del server. En tu ejemplo para `$name`:

```php
$name = html_entity_decode($name, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
```

---

**Nota de Seguridad:** El código que estás usando tiene **serios** problemas de seguridad. Por favor lee cómo utilizar [Sentencias Preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para armar un query, y siempre usando `mysqli`, la [extensión MySQL mejorada](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php).

- Esto también está muy bien explicado en [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/18233/127).

Answer (score 6):

después de la conexión al servidor, únicamente ingresa una linea como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");//conexión

mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8'); //linea a colocar
```

A partir de aquí ya puedes colocar tus consultas y demás que quieras utilizar

NOTA:mis campos de mysql son texto con cotejamiento `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Answer (score 3):

Otra opción es que uses `utf8_decode()`, tu utilizaste `utf8_encode()`.
Por ejemplo

Lo que ingreses en tu input por ejemplo (cigüeña -> tiene una Ü y Ñ) la guardas en una variable. luego antes de utilizar esta variable en tu consulta sql, le aplicas utf8_decode(). Por ejemplo $variable = utf8_decode($variable);

Comment: Podrías clarificar esto un poco mejor?

Comment: Lo que ingreses en tu input por ejemplo (cigüeña) la guardas en una variable. luego antes de utilizar esta variable en tu consulta sql, le aplicas utf8_decode(). Por ejemplo $variable = utf8_decode($variable);

Comment: @dantevalencia92 por favor edita tu respuesta y agrega esta explicación así quedaría mas completa. Salutes!

Comment: Listo, gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 1):

antes de guardar en la base de datos (collate sin especificar), puedes convertir los caracteres a entidades HTML

```
$string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

luego en el archivo php, agrega la siguiente cabecera

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

de esta forma, no sera necesario volver a transformar los datos antes de visualizarlos